# Evaluate $\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\sin^2(x)}{a + b\cos(x)}\ dx$ using a suitable contour

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, contour-integration

I need to find a good contour for $\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\sin^2(x)}{a + b\cos(x)}\ dx$ but I don't know which one to choose. Both a semicircular, and rectangular contour look ugly for this.

I've been looking at a semicircular contour of radius $2\pi$, but then I have the problem that I don't know whether the singularity is inside or outside the closed region.

If it helps, the answer is $\frac{2\pi}{b^2}\left[a - \sqrt{a^2 - b^2}\right]$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Note that the integral diverges for $a\le b$.  Therefore, we assume throughout the development that $a>b$.

We can simplify the task by rewriting the integrand as

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\sin^2(x)}{a+b\cos(x)}&=\frac{a}{b^2}-\frac{1}{b}\cos(x)-\left(\frac{a^2-b^2}{b^2}\right)\frac{1}{a+b\cos(x)}
\end{align}$$

Then, the integral of interest reduces to

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\sin^2(x)}{a+b\cos(x)}\,dx=\frac{2\pi a}{b^2}-\frac{a^2-b^2}{b^2}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{a+b\cos(x)}\,dx \tag 1$$

We enforce the substitution $z=e^{i x}$ in the integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$ and obtain

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{a+b\cos(x)}\,dx& =\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{a+b\left(\frac{z+z^{-1}}{2}\right)}\frac{1}{iz}\,dz\\\\
&=\frac2{ib}\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{(z+(a/b)-\sqrt{(a/b)^2-1})(z+(a/b)+\sqrt{(a/b)^2-1})}\,dz\\\\
&=2\pi i \frac2{ib} \frac{1}{2\sqrt{(a/b)^2-1}}\\\\
&=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}
\end{align}$$

Putting it all together, the integral of interest is

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\sin^2(x)}{a+b\cos(x)}\,dx=\frac{2\pi}{b^2}\left(a-\sqrt{a^2-b^2}\right)}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: (+1), Apparently there is more to this problem than would at first appear. I included some of the algebra to aid the OP.

Comment: Why would the integral diverge for a<=b? I did not understand

Comment: When $a\le b$, then there exist values of $x_0\in[0,2\pi]$ such that $a+b\cos(x_0)=0$ and the order of such zeros is $O(x-x_0)$.

Answer (score 6):

Here  is an  approach where  we do  not simplify  the  integral before
switching to complex variables.

Suppose we are looking to evaluate
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\sin^2 x}{a+b\cos x} dx.$$

Put $z=e^{ix}$ so that $dz = i e^{ix} \; dx = iz \; dx$
and use
$$\cos x = \frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}
\quad\text{and}\quad \sin x = \frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$$

to get
$$- \int_{|z|=1} \frac{(z-1/z)^2/4}{a+b(z+1/z)/2} \frac{1}{iz} dz
= i \int_{|z|=1} \frac{(z-1/z)^2/4}{bz^2/2 + az + b/2} \; dz
\\ = i \int_{|z|=1} \frac{1}{4z^2} 
\frac{z^4-2z^2+1}{bz^2/2 + az + b/2} \; dz.$$

The two poles here are at
$$\rho_{1,2} = \frac{-a\pm\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{b}
= \frac{a}{b} \left(-1\pm\sqrt{1-b^2/a^2}\right).$$

There is another pole at $z=0$ with residue
$$\frac{1}{4}
\left.\frac{4z^3-4z}{bz^2/2 + az + b/2} 
- \frac{1}{4} \frac{z^4-2z^2+1}{(bz^2/2 + az + b/2)^2}
(bz+a)\right|_{z=0} = - \frac{a}{b^2}.$$

Now  there are  several possibilities  here, we  discuss two  of them.

**First scenario.** Suppose $a$ and $b$ are real and $a\le b.$ We get

$$|\rho_{1,2}|
=\left| \frac{-a\pm i\sqrt{b^2-a^2}}{b}\right|
= \sqrt{\frac{a^2}{b^2}+\frac{b^2-a^2}{b^2}} = 1.$$

This means the two poles are located precisely on the circular contour
so the best  we can hope for  is to get the Cauchy  Principal Value of
the integral.  These are simple  poles so the contribution is half the
residue for both poles. We now compute these residues.

$$\mathrm{Res}_{z=\rho_{1,2}}
\frac{1}{4z^2} 
\frac{z^4-2z^2+1}{bz^2/2 + az + b/2}
= \frac{(\rho_{1,2}^2-1)^2}{4\rho_{1,2}^2}
\frac{1}{b\rho_{1,2} + a}.$$

Now we have by definition that
$$\rho_{1,2}^2 = -2a\rho_{1,2}/b - 1
\quad\text{and hence}\quad
\frac{\rho_{1,2}^2-1}{\rho_{1,2}}
= -2\frac{a}{b} - \frac{2}{\rho_{1,2}}.$$

Furthermore $$- \frac{1}{\rho_{1,2}} = 
2\frac{a}{b} + \rho_{1,2}
\quad\text{and therefore}\quad
\frac{\rho_{1,2}^2-1}{\rho_{1,2}} = 
2\frac{a}{b} + 2\rho_{1,2}.$$

Square this to get

$$4\frac{a^2}{b^2} + 8 \frac{a}{b}\rho_{1,2} + 4\rho_{1,2}^2
\\ = 4\frac{a^2}{b^2} + 8 \frac{a}{b}\rho_{1,2}
-8\frac{a}{b}\rho_{1,2} - 4
= 4\frac{a^2}{b^2} - 4.$$

This finally yields for the two residues

$$\left(\frac{a^2}{b^2} - 1\right)\frac{1}{b\rho_{1,2}+a}
= \pm \frac{a^2-b^2}{b^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}
= \pm \frac{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{b^2}.$$

Recall that we are currently  evaluating the case where both poles are
on the contour. We thus get for the value

$$i\times 2\pi i \times
\left(-\frac{a}{b^2} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{b^2}
- \frac{1}{2} \frac{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{b^2}\right)
= \frac{2\pi a}{b^2}.$$

**Second scenario.**  On the other hand  when $a\gt b$  we put $b/a=q$
with $0\lt q\lt 1$ a positive real number. We get

$$\rho_{1,2} = \frac{1}{q}
\left(-1 \pm \sqrt{1-q^2}\right).$$

Note however that  with the positive determination of  the square root
that we have been using we have that $-1-\sqrt{1-q^2} \lt -1$ and $1/q
\gt  1$ so  their product  is a  negative real  less than  $-1.$ Hence
$\rho_2$ is not inside the contour. Now

$$\rho_1\rho_2 = \frac{(-a)^2-(a^2-b^2)}{b^2} = 1$$

and hence  $\rho_1$ is the  inverse of $\rho_2.$ With  $|\rho_2|>1$ we
get $|\rho_1|<1.$  Therefore the pole at  $\rho_1$ is the  only one of
the two inside the contour and we get

$$i\times 2\pi i \times
\left(-\frac{a}{b^2} + \frac{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{b^2}\right)
= \frac{2\pi}{b^2} \left(a-\sqrt{a^2-b^2}\right).$$

Additional scenarios are left to the reader.

Comment: Marko, I had started to approach this as you have, and decided it was quite a bit easier to reduce the integral to a simpler form.  +1 for taking the brute force route. -Mark

Comment: Can you please explain how you got the denominator of the residue as "b*p_(1,2) + a"

Comment: Here is a directed pointer that has the explanation: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#Simple_poles).

Comment: Why isnt your answer for a<=b conforming with that for a>b?

Comment: Well in the first case the poles are right on the contour, so we get the CPV, in the second, we have two poles inside the contour, one from the pair. This depends on whether $a+b \cos(x) = 0$ has real solutions or not, which it does when $a\le b,$ causing the denominator to become singular.