# Integrating $\int_a^b\left[ \left(1 - \frac{a}{x} \right)\left(\frac{b}{x}-1 \right) \right]^\frac{1}{2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

We are interested in the following integration:
$$ \int_a^b \left[ \left(1 - \frac{a}{x} \right)\left(\frac{b}{x}-1 \right) \right]^{1/2} dx. $$

I try to use substitution with:
$$u = \left(1-\tfrac{a}{x}\right)\left(\tfrac{b}{x} -1\right) = (a+b)x^{-1} - 1 - (ab)x^{-2}.$$
$$ du = \left( (-a-b)x^{-2} + (2ab)(x^{-3}) \right)dx $$

or
$$  dx = du \left( \left( (-a-b)x^{-2} + (2ab)(x^{-3}) \right)^{-1} \right)$$

Now the integration becomes something ugly. I try integration by parts on the ugly part, and it becomes even uglier. Obviously, I don't see some easier ways. I would appreciate some advices or the solution!

Edit: It may be easier to see the problem as

$$ \int_a^b \left[ (a-x)(x-b)x^{-2}  \right]^{1/2} dx .$$

Comment: Mind if I ask where this came from? If $a<b$, the answer is supposedly $\frac\pi2(\sqrt b-\sqrt a)^2$, though I really cannot see how to arrive at it... :/

Comment: There is no details given. This is an exercise question in the 'warming up' section of a stats course. I tried many ways, nothing worked so far.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rescale the integration range with the following variable $u = \frac{x-a}{b-a}$ and the shorthand $q=\frac{b}{a}-1$ to simplify the integral

$$ I = \int_a^b \left[ \left(1 - \frac{a}{x} \right)\left(\frac{b}{x}-1 \right) \right]^{1/2} dx=aq^2\int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{u(1-u)}}{1+qu} du$$

Then, let $u=\sin^2 t$

\begin{align}
I &= 2a\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{q^2\sin^2 t\cos^2 t}{1+q\sin^2 t}dt\\
&= 2a\int_0^{\pi/2}\left( 1+q\cos^2 t-\frac{1+q}{1+q\sin^2 t}\right) dt
\end{align}

where

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\left( 1+q\cos^2 t\right) dt=\frac{\pi}{2}\left(1+\frac{q}{2}\right)$$

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1+q}{1+q\sin^2 t}dt=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{(1+q) d(\tan t)}{1+(1+q)\tan^2 t}=\frac{\pi}{2}\sqrt{1+q}$$

Thus

$$I= \frac{\pi}{2}(b+a-2\sqrt{ab})$$

Answer (score 11):

Let $0<a<b$.

By rewriting a bit we get

$$I(a,b)=\int_a^b\frac{\sqrt{(x-a)(b-x)}}x~\mathrm dx$$

Completing the square gives us

$$I(a,b)=\int_a^b\frac{\sqrt{\frac14(b-a)^2-\left(x-\frac{b+a}2\right)^2}}x~\mathrm dx$$

Substitute $\displaystyle\frac{b-a}2\sin(\theta)=x-\frac{b+a}2$ to get

$$I(a,b)=\frac{(b-a)^2}2\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos^2(\theta)}{(b-a)\sin(\theta)+b+a}~\mathrm d\theta$$

By manipulating symmetry,

$$I(a,b)=\frac{(b-a)^2}4\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos^2(\theta)}{(b-a)\sin(\theta)+b+a}~\mathrm d\theta$$

from which one may conclude

$$I(a,b)=\frac\pi2(\sqrt b-\sqrt a)^2$$

Comment: Thank you! What is the name of $\displaystyle\frac{b-a}2\sin(\theta)=x-\frac{b+a}2$ substitution? I would like to understand it.

Comment: It's just a trigonometric substitution.

Comment: Wow, this is a very cool answer.

Comment: Meh, I think this answer is very brute force and that there ought to be a much more elegant solution to be found.

Comment: is there a mistake though? In the first step you have denominator $x$. It should be $|x|$ right?

Comment: :p let $a>0\dots$

Comment: Beautiful solution!

Comment: Can you explain your final conclusion in more detail, I don't quite follow it?

Comment: @B.Mehta $\cos^2$ is $\pi$-periodic while $\sin$ goes through all of it's values on the given interval. Plot it and it should be clear.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Sorry, I misspoke - I meant to say that I don't follow the calculation of the final integral.

Comment: @B.Mehta it can be concluded using complex analysis or many other methods, as it is a standard integral. I am on mobile right now so searching for that type of question is difficult to do.

Comment: Ah, I see. As far as I can tell, the standard method for that integral is the tangent half-angle substitution, as your earlier version mentioned.

Comment: @B.Mehta due to the integral over the whole period, it can be handled much more cleanly though, but yes, it can still be brute forced.

Comment: Hmm, I'd be interested to see more details for that if you can find it.

Comment: Short and elegant !

Comment: @B.Mehta see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1777145/272831) for example.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Lovely, thanks!

Comment: I love the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,\dotsc\}$ and $\boldsymbol{a}=(a_1,a_2,\dotsc,a_n)$ be a positive sequence, that is, $a_k>0$ for $1\le k\le n$. The arithmetic and geometric means $A_n(\boldsymbol{a})$ and $G_n(\boldsymbol{a})$ of the positive sequence $\boldsymbol{a}$ are defined respectively as
\begin{equation*}
A_n(\boldsymbol{a})=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^na_k \quad \text{and}\quad
G_n(\boldsymbol{a})=\Biggl(\prod_{k=1}^na_k\Biggr)^{1/n}.
\end{equation*}
For $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus(-\infty,-\min\{a_k,1\le k\le n\}]$ and $n\ge2$, let $\boldsymbol{e}=(\overbrace{1,1,\dotsc,1}^{n})$ and
\begin{equation*}
G_n(\boldsymbol{a}+z\boldsymbol{e})=\Biggl[\prod_{k=1}^n(a_k+z)\Biggr]^{1/n}.
\end{equation*}

In Theorem 1.1 of the paper [1] below, by virtue of the Cauchy integral formula in the theory of complex functions, the following integral representation was established.

**Theorem 1.1.** *Let $\sigma$ be a permutation of the sequence $\{1,2,\dotsc,n\}$ such that the sequence $\sigma(\boldsymbol{a})=\bigl(a_{\sigma(1)},a_{\sigma(2)},\dotsc,a_{\sigma(n)}\bigr)$ is a rearrangement of $\boldsymbol{a}$ in an ascending order $a_{\sigma(1)}\le a_{\sigma(2)}\le \dotsm \le a_{\sigma(n)}$.
Then the principal branch of the geometric mean $G_n(\boldsymbol{a}+z\boldsymbol{e})$ has the integral representation
\begin{equation}\label{AG-New-eq1}\tag{1}
G_n(\boldsymbol{a}+z\boldsymbol{e})=A_n(\boldsymbol{a})+z-\frac1\pi\sum_{\ell=1}^{n-1}\sin\frac{\ell\pi}n \int_{a_{\sigma(\ell)}}^{a_{\sigma(\ell+1)}} \Biggl|\prod_{k=1}^n(a_k-t)\Biggr|^{1/n} \frac{\textrm{d}\,t}{t+z}
\end{equation}
for $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus(-\infty,-\min\{a_k,1\le k\le n\}]$.*

Taking $z=0$ in the integral representation \eqref{AG-New-eq1} yields
\begin{equation}\label{AG-ineq-int}\tag{2}
G_n(\boldsymbol{a})=A_n(\boldsymbol{a})-\frac1\pi\sum_{\ell=1}^{n-1}\sin\frac{\ell\pi}n \int_{a_{\sigma(\ell)}}^{a_{\sigma(\ell+1)}} \Biggl[\prod_{k=1}^n|a_k-t|\Biggr]^{1/n} \frac{\textrm{d}\,t}{t}\le A_n(\boldsymbol{a}).
\end{equation}
Taking $n=2,3$ in \eqref{AG-ineq-int} gives
$$
\frac{a_1+a_2}{2}-\sqrt{a_1a_2}\,=\frac1\pi\int_{a_1}^{a_2} \sqrt{\biggl(1-\frac{a_1}{t}\biggr) \biggl(\frac{a_2}{t}-1\biggr)}\, \textrm{d}\,t\ge0
$$
and
$$
\frac{a_1+a_2+a_3}{3}-\sqrt[3]{a_1a_2a_3}\,
=\frac{\sqrt{3}\,}{2\pi} \int_{a_1}^{a_3} \sqrt[3]{\biggl|
\biggl(1-\frac{a_1}{t}\biggr)
\biggl(1-\frac{a_2}{t}\biggr)
\biggl(1-\frac{a_3}{t}\biggr)\biggr|}\,\textrm{d}\,t\ge0
$$
for $0<a_1\le a_2\le a_3$.

Weighted version of the integral representation \eqref{AG-New-eq1} can be found in the paper [2] below. We recite the weighted version as follows.

For $n\ge2$, $\boldsymbol{a}=(a_1,a_2,\dotsc,a_n)$, and $\boldsymbol{w}=(w_1,w_2,\dotsc,w_n)$ with $a_k, w_k>0$ and $\sum_{k=1}^nw_k=1$,
the weighted arithmetic and geometric means $A_{w,n}(\boldsymbol{a})$ and $G_{w,n}(\boldsymbol{a})$ of $\boldsymbol{a}$ with the positive weight $\boldsymbol{w}$ are defined respectively as
\begin{equation}
A_{\boldsymbol{w},n}(\boldsymbol{a})=\sum_{k=1}^nw_ka_k
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
G_{\boldsymbol{w},n}(\boldsymbol{a})=\prod_{k=1}^na_k^{w_k}.
\end{equation}
Let us denote $\alpha=\min\{a_k,1\le k\le n\}$.
For a complex variable $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus(-\infty,-\alpha]$, we introduce the complex function
\begin{equation}\label{complex-geometric-mean}
G_{\boldsymbol{w},n}(\boldsymbol{a}+z)=\prod_{k=1}^n(a_k+z)^{w_k}.
\end{equation}
In Section 3 of the paper [2] below, with the aid of the Cauchy integral formula in the theory of complex functions, the following integral representation was established.

**Theorem 3.1.** *Let $0<a_k\le a_{k+1}$ for $1\le k\le n-1$ and $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus(-\infty,-a_1]$. Then the principal branch of the weighted geometric mean $G_{\boldsymbol{w},n}(\boldsymbol{a}+z)$ with a positive weight $\boldsymbol{w}=(w_1,w_2,\dotsc,w_n)$ has the integral representation
\begin{equation}\label{AG-New-eq1-weighted}\tag{3}
G_{\boldsymbol{w},n}(\boldsymbol{a}+z)=A_{\boldsymbol{w},n}(\boldsymbol{a})+z-\frac1\pi\sum_{\ell=1}^{n-1}\sin\Biggl[\Biggl(\sum_{k=1}^{\ell}w_k\Biggr)\pi\Biggr] \int_{a_\ell}^{a_{\ell+1}} \prod_{k=1}^n|a_k-t|^{w_k} \frac{\textrm{d}\,t}{t+z}.
\end{equation}*
Letting $z=0$ in the integral representation \eqref{AG-New-eq1-weighted} gives
\begin{equation}\label{AG-New-eq1-weighted-z=0}\tag{4}
G_{\boldsymbol{w},n}(\boldsymbol{a})=A_{\boldsymbol{w},n}(\boldsymbol{a})-\frac1\pi\sum_{\ell=1}^{n-1} \sin\Biggl[\Biggl(\sum_{k=1}^{\ell}w_k\Biggr)\pi\Biggr] \int_{a_\ell}^{a_{\ell+1}} \prod_{k=1}^n|a_k-t|^{w_k} \frac{\textrm{d}\,t}{t}\le A_{\boldsymbol{w},n}(\boldsymbol{a}).
\end{equation}
Setting $n=2$ in \eqref{AG-New-eq1-weighted-z=0} leads to
\begin{equation}\label{AG-New-n=2-weighted-z=0}\tag{5}
a_1^{w_1}a_2^{w_2}=w_1a_1+w_2a_2-\frac{\sin(w_1\pi)}\pi \int_{a_1}^{a_2} \biggl(1-\frac{a_1}{t}\biggr)^{w_1} \biggl(\frac{a_2}{t}-1\biggr)^{w_2} \textrm{d}\,t
\le w_1a_1+w_2a_2
\end{equation}
for $w_1,w_2>0$ such that $w_1+w_2=1$.

There have existed more closely related conclusions published in the following references below.

References

1. Feng Qi, Xiao-Jing Zhang, and Wen-Hui Li, *Levy--Khintchine representation of the geometric mean of many positive numbers and applications*, Mathematical Inequalities & Applications **17** (2014), no. 2, 719--729; available online at https://doi.org/10.7153/mia-17-53.
2. Feng Qi, Xiao-Jing Zhang, and Wen-Hui Li, *An integral representation for the weighted geometric mean and its applications*, Acta Mathematica Sinica-English Series **30** (2014), no. 1, 61--68; available online at https://doi.org/10.1007/s10114-013-2547-8.
3. Feng Qi and Bai-Ni Guo, *The reciprocal of the weighted geometric mean is a Stieltjes function*, Boletin de la Sociedad Matematica Mexicana, Tercera Serie **24** (2018), no. 1, 181--202; available online at https://doi.org/10.1007/s40590-016-0151-5.
4. Feng Qi and Bai-Ni Guo, *The reciprocal of the weighted geometric mean of many positive numbers is a Stieltjes function*, Quaestiones Mathematicae **41** (2018), no. 5, 653--664; available online at https://doi.org/10.2989/16073606.2017.1396508.
5. Feng Qi and Dongkyu Lim, *Integral representations of bivariate complex geometric mean and their applications*, Journal of Computational and Applied Mathematics **330** (2018), 41--58; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cam.2017.08.005.
6. Feng Qi, *Bounding the difference and ratio between the weighted arithmetic and geometric means*, International Journal of Analysis and Applications **13** (2017), no. 2, 132--135.
7. Feng Qi and Bai-Ni Guo, *The reciprocal of the geometric mean of many positive numbers is a Stieltjes transform*, Journal of Computational and Applied Mathematics **311** (2017), 165--170; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cam.2016.07.006.
8. Feng Qi, Xiao-Jing Zhang, and Wen-Hui Li, *The harmonic and geometric means are Bernstein functions*, Boletin de la Sociedad Matematica Mexicana, Tercera Serie **23** (2017), no. 2, 713--736; available online at https://doi.org/10.1007/s40590-016-0085-y.
9. Feng Qi, Xiao-Jing Zhang, and Wen-Hui Li, *An elementary proof of the weighted geometric mean being a Bernstein function*, University Politehnica of Bucharest Scientific Bulletin Series A---Applied Mathematics and Physics **77** (2015), no. 1, 35--38.
10. Bai-Ni Guo and Feng Qi, *On the degree of the weighted geometric mean as a complete Bernstein function*, Afrika Matematika **26** (2015), no. 7, 1253--1262; available online at https://doi.org/10.1007/s13370-014-0279-2.
11. Feng Qi, Xiao-Jing Zhang, and Wen-Hui Li, *Levy--Khintchine representations of the weighted geometric mean and the logarithmic mean*, Mediterranean Journal of Mathematics **11** (2014), no. 2, 315--327; available online at https://doi.org/10.1007/s00009-013-0311-z.
12. Feng Qi and Bai-Ni Guo, *Levy--Khintchine representation of Toader--Qi mean*, Mathematical Inequalities & Applications **21** (2018), no. 2, 421--431; available online at https://doi.org/10.7153/mia-2018-21-29.
13. Feng Qi, Viera Cernanova, Xiao-Ting Shi, and Bai-Ni Guo, *Some properties of central Delannoy numbers*, Journal of Computational and Applied Mathematics **328** (2018), 101--115; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cam.2017.07.013.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4256320/945479